# Convert XmlDocument object into an XmlNode object - C#?

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode

How do I convert an `XmlDocument` to a `XmlNode` in C#?  I need to send the entire `XmlDocument` object to as an input parameter to a .NET web service.

Comment: A complex type defined in the .NET Framework seems like a poor choice for a parameter to a Web Service. If the service is yours, you might look into changing the type to string. That would also let you call it from other languages/platforms with relative ease.

Comment: @TrueWill - The service is not mine, it is a third paty vendor serivce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A XmlDocument is a XmlNode, so you can just pass the document object.

Or you could send its DocumentElement, or any Node returned from an XPath query.

```
XmlDocument doc = null;
XmlNode node = doc;

XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/foo/bar");
```

No casting or converting is needed unless you need to disambiguate XmlNode from XmlDocument for a method with overloads for both parameter types. If this is the case, use either of the cast or `as` operators.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to refer to it explicitly as an XmlNode use "as":

```
XmlDocument doc = ...

XmlNode node = doc as XmlNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

An XmlDocument is derived from XmlNode, but you could also send the XmlDocument.DocumentElement which is an XmlElement but ultimately derived from XmlNode. You might need to check in XmlDocument.DocumentElement == null.